# Heartbeat, poll interval and session timeout for Spark Streaming with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Using Spark Streaming with Kafka - Direct Approach - [Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

Spark version - 2.3.2

Spark Streaming version - spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11

Problem : Need to run the steaming application with a batch interval of 10 minutes, but the default timeouts are very less than 10 mins so how to configure following parameters:

1. heartbeat.interval.ms
2. session.timeout.ms
3. group.max.session.timeout.ms
4. group.min.session.timeout.ms
5. max.poll.interval.ms

Given that the batch interval is 10 minutes.

Also, does setting these to certain values affect all the consumer groups (existing and the ones that may be added in future) ?

If yes, how to configure these params only for a specific consumer group ?

Comment: +1. Hope anyone could help since I got this warning when enable the auto commit setting: `Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. 
`